# How to implement Continue Statement with Filter Function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic

As I'm new to JS i **implemented filter function** on an array. I want to `skip some iterations`. How can I implement `continue statement etc` in filter function

Comment: `return false` will mean those elements wont be in the new Array, return true means they will ... there is no schrodinger cat option of yes and no in a filter - perhaps you're using filter for the wrong purpose - show the code

Comment: Please show the code. Filter should **never** require you to "skip" an item, since the result should take care of **every** item.

Answer (score 2):

Filter takes a callback function that returns a boolean, it doesn't skip iterations. If you would like to exclude an element from your result, your callback function should return false.

I.e. if I wanted to filter all odd numbers from an array:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const evenNumbers = numbers.filter(number => number % 2 === 0); // [2, 4, 6, 8]
```